# Using RxJS switchMap to only unsubscribe from streams with the same request URL/action payload (redux-observable epics)

Tags: javascript, redux, rxjs, redux-observable

I have an interface where the user may trigger calls to the same endpoint but with different params (in this case UUIDs). Up until now I've been enjoying the behavior of `switchMap` canceling my in-flight http requests whenever I dispatch a new redux action with the same type, and in this case I still want that behavior, but *only* if the new action's requested UUID (part of the action object) is the same as one that's already in progress. I'm not exactly sure of the right approach to this.

For example, after dispatching several actions at once, I'd hope that all of the ones with unique ids complete, but those that repeat an existing and not yet completed id cancel the previous request and take its place.

ex:

```
store.dispatch({ type: "GET_SOME_DATA", uuid: "1" })
store.dispatch({ type: "GET_SOME_DATA", uuid: "2" })
store.dispatch({ type: "GET_SOME_DATA", uuid: "2" })
store.dispatch({ type: "GET_SOME_DATA", uuid: "3" })
store.dispatch({ type: "GET_SOME_DATA", uuid: "2" })
// Get results back for '1', then '3', then '2' assuming equal response times.
// Only the duplicate uuid calls were cancelled, even though all have the same 'type'
```

I've tried using `.distinctUntilChanged((a, b) => a.uuid === b.uuid)` to filter the stream's input into .switchMap just to see what would happen, but that merely limits what actions reach the `switchMap`, and the behavior of canceling all but the most recent `GET_SOME_DATA` action related API call still occurs.

```
const getDataEpic = (action$) =>
  action$.ofType(GET_SOME_DATA)
    .switchMap(({ uuid }) => // would be great if the switchMap would only cancel existing streams with same uuid
      ajax.getJSON(`/api/datastuff/${uuid}`)
        .map((data) => successAction(uuid, data.values))
        .catch((err) => Observable.of(
          errorAction(uuid),
          setNotificationAction((err.xhr.response && err.xhr.response.message) || 'That went wrong'),
        ))
```

For now, I'm using `mergeMap`, but I'm worried that this could cause issues like I've run into with live searching where an older request might resolve after the most recent one, causing my redux store to be updated with old data since mergeMap doesn't cancel the Observable streams like switchMap does... is there a way for me to look at current RxJS Ajax requests and cancel those with the new action's url, or a better solution that I'm clearly missing?

Cheers!

Edit: I'm wondering if changing `switchMap` to `mergeMap`, then chaining `takeUntil` and canceling on other GET_SOME_DATA actions would be a proper approach, or if that would just make all requests cancel immediately?
For example

```
const getDataEpic = (action$) =>
  action$.ofType(GET_SOME_DATA)
    .mergeMap(({ uuid }) =>
      ajax.getJSON(`/api/datastuff/${uuid}`)
        .takeUntil(
          action$.ofType(GET_SOME_DATA).filter(laterAction => laterAction.uuid === uuid)
        )
        .map((data) => successAction(uuid, data.values))
        .catch((err) => Observable.of(
          errorAction(uuid),
          setNotificationAction((err.xhr.response && err.xhr.response.message) || 'That went wrong'),
    ))
```

Edit2: Apparently the `takeUntil` addition appears to be working! I'm not sure if it's 100% on the up and up in terms of being appropriate but I'd love some feedback. I'd also like to support a manual cancellation option as well, would the method discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48710319/7027882) be the proper implementation?

Edit3: I think this is my final, working version. Removed the destructuring of the Redux action in the mergeMap just in case somebody newer to redux-observables comes across this:

```
const getDataEpic = (action$) =>
  action$.ofType(GET_SOME_DATA)
    .mergeMap((action) =>
      ajax.getJSON(`/api/datastuff/${action.uuid}`)
        .takeUntil(Observable.merge(
          action$.ofType(MANUALLY_CANCEL_GETTING_DATA)
            .filter((cancelAction) => cancelAction.uuid === action.uuid),
          action$.ofType(GET_SOME_DATA)
            .filter((laterAction) => laterAction.uuid === action.uuid),
        ))
        .map((data) => successAction(action.uuid, data.values))
        .catch((err) => Observable.of(
          errorAction(action.uuid),
          setNotificationAction((err.xhr.response && err.xhr.response.message) || 'That went wrong'),
    ))
```

And the observed network behavior from rapidly clicking everything in sight. Only the non-duplicated id requests went through!

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use the **groupBy** operator to handle streams with the same uuid and apply the useful **switchMap** behavior on every uuid action stream:

```
action$.ofType(GET_SOME_DATA)
.groupBy(
    ({ uuid }) => uuid, // group all the actions by uuid
    x => x,
    group$ => group$.switchMap(_ => Observable.timer(5000)) // close existing streams if no event of a grouped action is emitted 5 seconds in a row (prevents memory leaks)
)
.mergeMap(actionsGroupedByUuid$ => 
    actionsGroupedByUuid$.switchMap(({ uuid }) => 
        ajax.getJSON(`/api/datastuff/${uuid}`)
            .map((data) => successAction(uuid, data.values))
            .catch((err) => Observable.of(
                errorAction(uuid),
                setNotificationAction((err.xhr.response && err.xhr.response.message) || 'That went wrong'),
            )) 
    )
);
```

Comment: Never knew about the groupBy operator, but semantically looks like the perfect 'correct' solution for this example, thank you!

Could you help me understand why we need to perform a mergeMap around the switchMap instead of immediately piping the output of groupBy into switchMap?


I also ran across this on github after searching for 'groupBy + switchMap' and it matches! https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/2147#issuecomment-262008911

Comment: The mergeMap is applied on *all groups*. You want all groups (indivudal UUID) to run in parallel and then within each group to survive only the latest one. If you would apply switchMap immediately after the groupBy, you would only get one group (one UUID) instead of all.